# Horizontal spacing before and after inline math mode with custom font

Tags: math-mode, spacing, ebgaramond, horizontal-spacing

I'm using EB Garamond with text and math. The problem is that inline math expressions seem to be way too close to the normal text, like the font hasn't been configured correctly.

I'm looking to fix this by adding something similar to the regular italic corrections but for math mode.

Here's the packages I'm using.

```tex
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
```

I've attached a picture of some math mixed with text. I hope you'll agree with me that the spacing looks way off *in some places*.
It's not just the large spacing within math mode vs text that is jarring (although I'd like to know how to balance that too), but especially the last line for example has the `\(a+ib\)` *looking* way too close to the preceding word.

[image: sample of math mixed with text]

I've made a more minimal example, but it has less of a spacing issue before and after math mode, but really bad spacing in math mode particularly:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
all the elements \(a+ib,c+id\in\mathbb{Q}[i]\) \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Compiled with XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX, both just as bad.

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you @Mensch !